# React Query to store global state for user?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Is there a way to use react-query to store global state for user, if user is logged in or not?

Right not currently I am only storing cookie as bearer token and refresh token

And I am forcing react query to hit an API endpoint that checks if user has valid bearer token

So right now its making unnecessary requests and getting failed error response if use is not logged in.

What can I do to store user info when user is logged in, so that I don't have to make unnecessary requests to /verify endpoint?

Comment: Do you have control over the API? It is common to pass the (bearer) token in the request header (usually "Authorization"), and the API's backend will verify the token. If so, you can store your token in the local SessionStorage (or LocalStorage, if it should survive a refresh), and put this into the request headers each time you send a request to the API. Another options might be cookies, but these are usually set by the backend and resend automatically by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options to do it. But most common are:

1. Keep auth data in `localStorage` and before API call check if the `authToken` is not expired.
2. Keep auth data in the cookie and do the same

This will help you to avoid unnecessary requests and you will be able to make requests even after page reload/closing the browser tab